R usmap package uncompressing
I am trying to use the USmap package in R for US mapping. I would use the maps package, but they don't include Alaska and Hawaii.
When I try to create a df from the usmap package - It results in a compressed file - each row corresponds to a state, with a column named 'geom' that has all the coordinate data. See image of df
I used this code to decompress the data. That seems to work, but I have no idea how to include state names.
As an aside, the usmap package used to be in a decompressed df. Why did this change and is there a way all together to avoid having to do this workaround?
Code:
library(sf)
us_states <- usmap::us_map() ## creates compressed df - used to not be compressed 


us_map_long <- st_as_sf(us_states) %>% ## decompressed, but no state names 

  st_cast("POLYGON") %>% 

  st_coordinates() %>%   

  as.data.frame()    


What exactly do you need to do with the data frame that has a row for each vertex of each polygon? It may be possible to do what you want to do without that.

I have been using ggplot to create maps. In the past, I used (left_join) to add a variable for states, then created a map to display that variable. I need to be able to quickly add/change/remove variables.

You should still be able to do that with the us_states object that is created directly with us_map(). You can join other data frames to that one.

As for why usmap organizes the data this way, it's worth it to read up on the "simple features" standard from the R sf package documentation. The "compressed df" is a simple-features (sf) data.frame that contains a list column of all the geometries for each feature (record). This makes many operations, including joins, much simpler, hence the change. As qdread said, you should be able to join any dataset to us_states() based on the state name or FIPS code, without needing to mess with the geometry list-column.
